# The difference between maven remote repository and nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I can use a maven remote repository with this config in maven settings.xml file for organization owned custom repository:

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
       <id>org.source.repo</id>
       <url>https://172.18.100.10/maven2/</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

My question is this:
Does **Nexus** act the same and just provides some more functionality (like proxy, etc) or they have completely different usage?

Comment: The name term `remote repository` is a **general** name for a tool like Nexus (or Artifactory, https://github.com/artipie/artipie, https://reposilite.com/ or other tools like that see https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html). Another remote repository is the [central repository](https://central.sonatype.com/) which is driven by Nexus as well ...technically a remote repository can even be a simple apache http/nginx or alike but those would lack some functionality...

Comment: What service (application) is running behind the url `https://172.18.100.10/maven2/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name term `remote repository` is a **general** name for a tool like Nexus (or Artifactory, https://github.com/artipie/artipie, https://reposilite.com/ or other tools like that see https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html). Another remote repository is the [central repository](https://central.sonatype.com/) which is driven by Nexus as well ...technically a remote repository can even be a simple apache http/nginx or alike but those would lack some functionality...